# Why "Fbclid" is not enough for attribution?

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel, conversion-tracking

I've been tormented for a few months by this question!

I don't understand how Facebook pixel works deeply (and I assume only FB devs Know) but I have a few questions, if anyone can help me:

1- I launch a conversion campaign on Facebook ads, a specific ad gets a click, and a unique "fbclid" gets attributed to that click (?); if a conversion happens, and I send back the fbclid, Isn't Facebook supposed to be able to attribute it to the specific ad that generated that click, thus that fbclid?  I thought that was the whole point of having a Server-to-server solution? since Apple announced iOS updates blocking cookies?

I come from an affiliate marketing background, we use tools like "Everflow" to track affiliate links, with a "transaction_id", that is, a unique value generated on every outgoing click. I thought the same logic would apply to fbclid.

Why are we asked to pass back to Facebook so much data when a conversion happens, like a name, email, etc... to be able to attribute the conversion to a campaign

( AND EVEN SO! Our Tracking is only 80% Accurate!!)

2- Can anyone explain how Facebook pixel actually works ? ignoring the Server to server (Conversion API ) solution, how does the Facebook base code + the conversion event script work to be able to attribute a conversion to a specific campaign? does it store the fbclid in your cookies? and when a conversion happens execute a request to Facebook?

3- AM I talking about 2 Different things here: FB attribution to campaigns VS Event matching? are they the same concept? Why is this so confusing to me? I couldn't find someone that's asking the same question, is it because I am missing something very obvious?

Thank you in advance!!